# How to install custom Xamarin.Forms.<version>.nupkg in VisualStudio 2017?

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget, visual-studio-2017

After creating .../.nuspec/Xamarin.Forms.9.9.1.nupkg via a variant of https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/wiki/How-to-Build-Xamarin.Forms-NuGet (e.g., I built locally instead of VSTS), how do I install it for use as my copy of Xamarin.Forms in my various projects in VisualStudio 2017?

One would think that configuring a NuGet Package Source via VS2017 > Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings aiming at that .../.nuspec directory would simply cause NuGet to pick it up from there, but, no, it doesn't find any nuget there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!  The NuGet Package Source via VS2017 > Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings needs to aim at that ... directory without the /.nuspec

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.